# Can not save zsh instead of shell to terminal

Tags: terminal

Screen Shot 2020-05-12 at 1.22.57 PM.zip

I can't seem to make it as a default in changing shell to zsh. When I want to close the terminal it says that if I close it it will go back to shell so does anyone know how to save it so it stays as zsh?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot doesn't seem to have uploaded. What terminal, current shell and command are you using? You could try:

```
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```